# Running a process with current credentials

Tags: c#, pdf, active-directory, windows-authentication, wkhtmltopdf

I am developing an Umbraco intranet site where I call wkhtmltopdf.exe to create some pdfs. Those pdfs are using a main page for the content and two additional pages for header and footer. Things worked pretty fine as long as I had the site without authentication. We want to use our Active Directory accounts to login to the site and thus I have enabled windows authentication. The routine for running this is to click a button that process the page and either shows the pdf on the browser or downloads it. In any case it is the same process. In visual studio when running with debugging when it comes to the first part of the code (var p = ...) it throws an exception "Message = "No process is associated with this object." because it fails to authenticate. I can see that when I pause the code just after its execution and using the visual studio inspector. The method runs to the end but because of the error I mentioned before it produces a blank pdf. If I hardcode username and password then it works fine.

Site is running in my local dev enviroment in iis express. Since Windows Authentication is enabled when I browse to the site the first time I have to login. Wkhtmltopdf.exe is located in the local drive - it is not on the website. The initial setup is based on the method described here http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.se/2012/04/making-pdfs-from-html-in-c-using.html Only users that are part of our Active Directory domain will have access to the website but since we use the same accounts to login to windows then windows authentication will do the trick :)

```
public static void HtmlToPdf(string outputFilename, string[] urls, 
        string[] options = null,
        bool streamPdf = false,
        string pdfHtmlToPdfExePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe")
    {
        string urlsSeparatedBySpaces = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Determine inputs
            if ((urls == null) || (urls.Length == 0))
            {
                throw new Exception("No input URLs provided for HtmlToPdf");
            }
            urlsSeparatedBySpaces = String.Join(" ", urls); //Concatenate URLs


            var p = new System.Diagnostics.Process()
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = pdfHtmlToPdfExePath,
                    Arguments = ((options == null) ? "" : String.Join(" ", options)) + " "  + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + " -",
                    UseShellExecute = false, // needs to be false in order to redirect output
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    RedirectStandardInput = true, // redirect all 3, as it should be all 3 or none
                    WorkingDirectory = string.Empty
                }
            };

            p.Start();

            var output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            byte[] buffer = p.StandardOutput.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(output);
            p.WaitForExit(60000);
            p.Close();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            if (!streamPdf)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='" + outputFilename + "'");
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            throw new Exception("Problem generating PDF from HTML, URLs: " + urlsSeparatedBySpaces + ", outputFilename: " + outputFilename, exc);
        }
    }
```

I tested this with LoadUserProfile = true but that didnt't help also. After reading throughout various forum posts the only suggested solution that I saw was to force loging in the process by using UserName, Password etc. But that is bad since the user is already logged in and we could/should use something like CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials .

A workaround that I came too was to use DefaultCredentials in requests to save the htmls locally where I can access them without a problem and create the pdfs but even that is a painstaking process, since i need to create printable css and javascripts and download them etc etc. This is my last solution which I have implemented at 80% but seems nasty also. Here is another code sample how I grab the webpages.

```
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

So to sum up. Wkhtmltopdf fails to authenticate itself so that it can grab the desired pages and turn them to pdf. Is there any neat way to make the process able to authenticate itself with current user's credentials that I am logged in to the site so that it can access the pages?

Comment: i do not fully understand the whole scenario. So there are users which access the web page ? Where does wkhtmltopdf run? is this a server component or is this running on the client and accesses the web pages?

Comment: Hey sorry for having some vague parts. Wkhtmltopdf.exe is located in the local drive - it is not on the website. The initial setup is based on the method described here http://icanmakethiswork.blogspot.se/2012/04/making-pdfs-from-html-in-c-using.html Only users that are part of our Active Directory domain will have access to the website. Hope that I have clarified a bit my question now.

Comment: okay. now i understand. So the Wkhtmltopdf.exe runs under the context of the currently logged on user. Right? Now it would be interesting what type of exception is thrown

Comment: Yeap. It runs under the IIS.Express in my local dev environment and obviously that "user" is different from the actual user that is logged in the site. Thus the process crashes since it can't access the webpage to retrieve the content.

Comment: if you run everything on your local dev machine (IIS express web site as well as the Wkhtmltopdf.exe which is not started under another user), the user is the same. In order to test this, you can start e.g. calc.exe and then open the task manager and you can see, that both, the IIS express and clac.exe are running under your context. So what happens if you open internet explorer and access this web site yourself?
And what kind of error does Wkhtmltopdf.exe give out?

Comment: When I get to the site myself the first time I have to login (Windows Authentication). All the processes run under the current windows user, as checked from the task manager. So what I want to achieve is to be able to use the credentials from the logged in user so that the process can manage to pass the authentication and get the pages. 

The method I want to achieve with that I have successfully achieved in my alternate method using defaultcredentials which are used to successfully retrieve the page.


The error message that I get is.
Message = "No process is associated with this object."

Comment: Ah okay. you are being prompted for username/password when you try to access the web site? Even when it runs locally in IIS Express? It looks to me that you are having an authentication issue. And where does "No process is associated with this object" originate from? Your code or from Wkhtmltopdf.exe ?

Comment: you're providing far to little information on the whole topic

Comment: I added those details to my original post. Thanks for your feedback and I hope that it is clearer now :) Yeap as I said initially it is a matter of authentication and how to achieve that.

Comment: where does "No process is associated with this object" originate from? Your code or from Wkhtmltopdf.exe ? And what happens if you host your application on an IIS (on windows server) ?

Comment: Visual studio in debugging throws an exception in the first snippet of the code that I have posted that calls the wkhtmltopdf.exe. When I inspect I found this message. It is 100% related to authentication because when I test with hardcoded username and password everything works as it should. However the point is to avoid the user entering the password again. I also tried to get the users password with code behind, something like Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) but that has failed also.

Comment: The first snippet you posted doesn't contain any `p.Start()` statement. How can the code fail in there?

Comment: Well p.Start() comes exactly after the code first code block. To clarify the whole thing "doesn't crash" but when I inspect the var p = ... block after it has executed I can see the exception.

Comment: then please update your first code snippet with the whole code and tell us, where this happens

Comment: Yes, i know that there is p.Start(). But you didn't even provide any additional information. So i've enough to ask and ask again for more info and you barely provide them in a useful way. Sorry

Comment: The code I am using is the same as the example in the link I have given. I have pasted the whole code of the method. And my question is still if I can use some kind of authentication for the process, since I am 100% sure that this causes the crash. Anyhow thanks for your help and sorry for not providing all the related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I Use Rotativa a wrapper for Wkhtmltopdf.

To get it working on iis, I created a separate user account with enough access to run Wkhtmltopdf.exe. Then Pass the User Name & Password to Wkhtmltopdf with the switches.

```
public virtual ActionResult PrintInvoice(int id) {
        var invoice = db.Invoices.Single(i => i.InvoiceId == id);
        var viewmodel = Mapper.Map<InvoiceViewModel>(invoice);

        var reportName = string.Format(@"Invoice {0:I-000000}.pdf", invoice.InvoiceNo);
        var switches = String.Format(@" --print-media-type --username {0} --password {1} ", 
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PdfUserName"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PdfPassword"]); 
        ViewBag.isPDF = true;
        return new ViewAsPdf("InvoiceDetails", viewmodel) {
            FileName = reportName,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Portrait,
            PageSize = Rotativa.Options.Size.A4,
            CustomSwitches = switches
        };
    }
```

It appears the pages running within Wkhtmltopdf.exe run with the current users credentials, but the Wkhtmltopdf.exe itself needs rights to execute on the server.

This works on iis when deployed. On Cassini in VS2012 it works for me with no credentials, but in vs2013 on iis express I'm still having trouble when it comes to picking up resources like css & images.

Same solution to run over SSL:
[Rotativa and wkhtmltopdf no CSS or images on iis6 over HTTPS, but fine on HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432973/rotativa-and-wkhtmltopdf-no-css-or-images-on-iis6-over-https-but-fine-on-http)

Comment: Hello. I have abandoned that project for the time being since it is not critical. But thanks for your suggestion. I will try that when I have time. There is also a couple of alternatives I have found but your solution would help because I do not have to change much. I will get back to it when I try your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xh507fc5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [spawn wkhtmltopdf under the context of the impersonated user](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889251).

*Note: turning on ASP.NET impersonation is very likely to decrease performance*.